# Looking to Optimize MySQL execution time to solve a constraining bottleneck in my Database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, architecture

PROBLEM: I have 1000 devices that every 5 minutes are required to send a json post request to a command server. The command server has a queue of requests, and uses workers to parses the json file and queries the database with the information. I have a bottleneck that exists on the database level that makes this challenging.

For the sake of example suppose this was this information collected from a particular sensor:

```
data: {
       'time': '2017-10-05 17:25:00',
       'squirrels spotted': 1,
       'spotter_sensor': 992
}
```

The table I insert the data in the database looks like this below. I aggregate the 5 minute counts into their latest collected hour. So the latest hour shows the latest data from 5 minutes ago.

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------
| spotter_sensor_id | hour_collected       | squirrels spotted |
|--------------------------------------------------------------
|    992            | 2017-10-05 17:00:00  | 5                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

In order to do this I have: (pseudo code)

```
UPDATE table SET squirrels_spotted = squirrels_spotted + '$squirrels spotted' 
      where spotter_sensor_id = '992'
        and hour_collected = '$hour_collected'
IF (ROWS_AFFECTED == 0)
 INSERT INTO table VALUES(992, '$new_hour', 0)
```

When profiling the execution time of the database to execute the above statement for an existing hour in SQL I got:

[image]

> (for a medium MySQL AWS RDS Instance)

The problem is 2 seconds for a simple update is too long. That only allows me to process only 150 sensors in those 5 minutes. I don't understand why it takes so long to perform one query.

Do I have to change the business logic since it is impossible processing those sensors all in 5 minutes or is there a better way?

Comment: can the create table statement be added to the question please?  the indexes will play a role in this.  if it does not have an autoincrementng column, share how many rows you have in the table.

Comment: The table should have an compound index on (spotter_sensor_id, hour_collected). Also, your (pseudo) code should be inserting the amount you were trying to increment with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance, you need `INDEX(spotter_sensor_id, hour_collected)`

For less code, you need IODKU:

```
INSERT INTO table
        (spotter_sensor_id, hour_collected, squirrels_spotted)
    VALUES
        ('992', '$hour_collected, $squirrels_spotted)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        squirrels_spotted = squirrels_spotted + VALUES(squirrels_spotted);
```